Tower of module-endomorphism rings
Let $R$ be a ring with nonzero left ideal $A$. Define $E_1=\text{End}({}_RA)$ viewed as a ring of right operators on $A$ and $E_2=\text{End}(A_{E_1})$ viewed as a ring of left operators on $A$. Similarly, define $E_{2k+1}=\text{End}({}_{E_{2k}}A)$ and $E_{2k}=\text{End}(A_{E_{2k-1}})$.
Do we have a general relation between $E_{2k}$ and between $E_{2k+1}$?
For example, is $R \hookrightarrow E_2 \hookrightarrow E_4 \hookrightarrow \cdots$ in general?
If $R$ has double centralizer property, then $R \cong E_2$. When do $E_{2k}$ for $k \ge 1$ have this property?
What can we say about the relation between $E_{2k+1}$?

If $A$ is any abelian group we can define the commutant or centralizer $R'$ of a subring $R \subseteq \text{End}(A)$ to be
$$R' = \{ f \in \text{End}(A) : \forall r \in R : fr = rf \}.$$
This is always another subring, so we can iterate taking commutants; your sequence is $E_1 = R', E_{k+1} = E_k'$ (we can't quite start at $E_0 = R$ because in your setup this is not required to be a subring). In this approach it's not necessary to discuss left and right actions separately. Now it's straightforward to see that for any subrings $R, S$ we have

If $R \subseteq S$, then $S' \subseteq R'$, and
$R \subseteq R''$

from which it follows both that $R''' \subseteq R'$ and that $R' \subseteq R'''$, hence that $\boxed{ R' = R''' }$ for any $R$. So the sequence has at most three distinct entries $E_0 = R, E_1 = R', E_2 = R''$ and then is $2$-periodic from this point on.
In this setup $A$ can be an arbitrary left module over $R$, there's no need to restrict attention to left ideals.

Very nice, thanks. What you wrote reminds me of field extensions: If $H$ is a subgroup of the Galois group $G$ of $E/F$, and $H'$ is the fixed field of $H$ and for any intermediate field $K$, $K'=Aut_{K}(F)$, then $K'=K'''$ and $H'=H'''$ and $K \subset K''$ and $H \subset H''$

Yes, these are both examples of Galois connections between posets (also known as adjunctions): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection
